# find the average of XYZ coordinates from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file like this
4.1487753725        0.4897939031       -1.1544368391

```
      4.2506913391       -0.7956710981       -1.3259877915

      3.9695031790       -2.0510342090       -1.4046097748

      3.4511646710       -3.2198662126       -1.5663430729

      2.5153044314       -4.0864073852       -1.8261543415

      1.3426382182       -4.6013891404       -2.0548734271

      0.0357806676       -4.6784799702       -1.9373871780

     -1.2266940176       -4.3033231617       -2.0028733656

      3.7028052845        1.6723951131       -0.9012966155

      2.5960399662        2.3563000246       -0.6873344353

      1.3596707979        2.6502036973       -0.7101050335

      0.0775001020        2.6467774205       -0.7896014849

     -1.1666635197        2.2212285825       -1.0060401024
```

........

i want to do average of first 18 lines and then the next remaining lines

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want an average *every* 18 lines, or just the average of the *first* 18 lines, and then the average of all the lines after that?

Comment: I have X Y Z coordinates file having length of 36 lines, i want to split these 36 lines into two parts containing 18 lines in each case and i want to do average of those 18 X Y Z coordinates in both he cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with I/O, you'll need to read in your data file and cast your data to a numeric type. Here's the first 18 lines averaged, and then the average of the remaining points, ***assuming your data is stored in*** `"data.txt"`, and is stored in the same directory where this code is running.

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as data_file:
    data = [line.strip().split() for line in data_file.readlines()]
    data = [[float(x) for x in line] for line in data]


first_18_avg = [[sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*data[:18])]]
avg_of_rest = [[sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*data[18:])]]
```

If you want a function which will take averages *every 18 lines,* which seems more reasonable to me and what I'm kind of assuming you meant originally:

```py
def find_avg_xyz(data):
    return [[sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*data)]]


avg_every_18_lines = []
a, b = 0, 18
for _ in range(len(data) // 18):
    avg_every_18_lines.append(find_avg_xyz(data[a:b]))
    a, b = b, b + 18
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but the thing is I have 50 more file containing the same data, it is possible to read and perform same calculation for those files without changing the file names.

Comment: What do you mean, "without changing the file names"? Just put whatever your file names are into that `with open(...)` to open whatever file you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification. It's really helpful, half of my problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

does this help ?

```
input = [[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
average = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*input)]
print(average)
```

Comment: I have so many files I cant able to do [ , , ,] in each case. Is there any other way to resolve this.    and thank you for the help